# Make a Search Method generic using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a method in my project that repeats over and over:

```
public PAC PAC_GetByCodiPac(string codiPac)

{

var sel = _gam.PAC.Where(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);

            if (sel.Count() > 0)
                return sel.First();
            return null;
        }
```

The table PAC means (patient), so I have these methods for all the tables I have.
How can I make a generic method for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me, what _gam is?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Linq2Sql? Something else?

Comment: I think Where() and FirstOrDefault() extension methods are already generic enough for your need

Comment: With the call to `Count`, you iterate over the whole data set, even If you only return the first match. Instead you should go with `_gam.PAC.FirstOrDefault(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a generic method that lets you specify any table and any predicate for records from that table then you can't really get any better than the built-in `Where<T>(...)` and (as others have already pointed out) the `FirstOrDefault<T>(...)` extension methods.

Your code would then look like so:

```
var result = _gam.PAC.Where(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac).FirstOrDefault();
// OR
var result = _gam.PAC.FirstOrDefault(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);
```

The best you could get then, writing your own generic method, would be this:

```
public T FirstOrDefault<T>(IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    // OR
    // return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

And that is really just redundant. Especially when your calling code would be actually longer using the helper method:

```
var result = FirstOrDefault(_gam.PAC, pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);
// versus
var result = _gam.PAC.FirstOrDefault(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);
```

And even worse, your code is no longer using a fluent, composable syntax. This just makes readability and maintenance more difficult.

If you stick with using the `IQueryable<T>` extension methods then you can do composition like this:

```
var result = _gam.PAC
        .Where(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac)
        .Where(pac => pac.SomeOtherProperty == someOtherValue)
        .FirstOrDefault();
// OR

var result = (from pac in _gam.PAC
              where pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac
              where pac.SomeOtherProperty == someOtherValue
              select pac).FirstOrDefault();
```

One very important thing to note here is that the `predicate` parameter in the `IQueryable<T>.Where<T>(...)` extension method is of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. This allows the `IQueryable<T>` provider to construct the native SQL (or other native provider query) at the very last moment before returning a result.

Not using `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` means that your query would be the equivalent of this:

```
var result =
    _gam.PAC
        .ToArray()
        .Where(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

And that would mean the query will load every record from the "PAC" table into memory before selecting the first filtered result and throwing out the rest of the results.

The bottom-line is that by making a generic helper method you are **rewriting existing framework code** and you open yourself to **performance and maintenance issues** while also **reducing code readability**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, what do you think it would be better the method above written by zespri(which is generic) or having in my BL many methods(GetByCodi using FirstOrDefult) such as tables in my DB? What would be better thinking in perfonmace and speed.

Comment: @ramo2712 - No offense to zespri - he's written some very advanced code that produces a less expressive function that the built-in `Where` method. I don't know why you need to have many methods in your BL. Your BL should either constrain you to only the methods that you should access - which means you shouldn't need many methods - or it should provide an expressive way to access your data so standard LINQ is good there. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a solution to the project website and a data access library in which I have as GetByCodi methods. So do not write LINQ code in aspx pages, just call my library methods, and library are growing considerably(the database is big), so I try to make generic methods. Thank you very much for your answer. I make methods like print a generic one, but with this I would use this                var result = _gam.PAC.FirstOrDefault(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);

Answer (score 2):

Here is your generic method. Note, that as others pointed out FirstOrDefault is better than count and then first, so I'm using it here. But it's also possible to write the expression so that it mimics what your original code does. Please let me know if you need additional help with this.

```
public static T GetByCodi<T>(IQueryable<T> table, string codi, string fieldName) where T : class
{
    // x
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression currentExpression = parameter;
    Type currentType = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo property = currentType.GetProperty(fieldName);

    // x.CODI_xxx
    currentExpression = Expression.Property(currentExpression, property);

    // x.CODI_xxx == codi
    currentExpression = Expression.Equal(currentExpression, Expression.Constant(codi));

    // x => x.CODI_xxx == codi
    LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(currentExpression, parameter);

    return table.FirstOrDefault((Func<T, bool>)lambdaExpression.Compile());
}
```

You use it like this:

```
PAC xxx = GetByCodi<PAC>(_gam.PAC, codiPac, "CODI_PAC");
```

**Edit 1**:
I changed the code according to the comment so that you can pass arbitrary ID field name in.

Comment: This method work great on all the tables that ID begin with "CODI_" but there are some tables in my DataBase whit diferents ID names. There is a way to know the ID of the table, and them the methods makes automatic whatever the name of the ID.

Comment: I change the code above so that it takes the id field name as a parameter that you can pass in. If you satisfied with the answer please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I see that what you asked is a very straight forward `where` query even doesn't require to have have it on a separate method.
Also you can simply enhance your query link the following:

```
public PAC PAC_GetByCodiPac(string codiPac)
{
   return _gam.PAC.FirstOrDefault(pac => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);
}
```

FirstOrDefault will return the first item on the array, if not it will return null.

Comment: even if I would not put this into seperate methods for every table, `FirstOrDefault` is the way to go. Inline `FirstOrDefault`!

Comment: exactly, but sometimes we have to create simple methods in BL and might contain only one line but it's a business method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking for this, but this method could be in a static class and method and so you'd be able to call it from everywhere.

Comment: He wants to do this not only for table PAC, but also for all other tables in his DB.

Comment: I'm not sure about his problem, but he says this method "repeats over and over", I supose it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution will be:

```
//a generic method
private PAC PAC_GetPAC(Func<PAC, bool> predicate)
{
   return _gam.PAC.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}

public PAC PAC_GetPACById(long id)
{
   return PAC_GetPAC(p => p.ID == id);
}

public PAC PAC_GetByCodiPac(string codiPac)
{
   return PAC_GetPAC(p => pac.CODI_PAC == codiPac);
}
```

Comment: again, I think this will only work for table PAC, because _gam.PAC will give you this particular table. He seems to want to be able to pass the table in, so that it can be called for *any* table.